# WP WC CLI - WooCommerce setup store with wp-cli

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, wp-cli

WP-CLI provides a few commands to manage coupons, orders and more.

Is a command exist to setup a store with wp-cli(The setup screen with store settings and WooCommerce store pages)?
Something like:

```
wp wc store create --store_page_name=Shop ...
```

Comment: any news on this? i just checked out the reference for wc cli and there does not seem to be anything related to setting up woocommerce. although, the store page name should be the wordpress title, i guess. i would like to do everything that is possible in the setup wizard, but with wc cli only...as far as i can tell, you cannot even set the shop address or other basic data.

Comment: found it! it is not in wp wc, if you use `wp option list` you will see all the woocommerce options too - for example `wp option update woocommerce_store_address` to set the store address. you can do that with a LOT of options, it is just not a single command. hope that helps, more than 3 years later :)

Comment: To limit the number of results ```wp option list --search="woo*" > woocommerceoptions.txt``` Thanks @luschn